# Expired timestamp not recognized by check function javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I'm using this code to check a timestamp:

```
var timestamp = 1599490350898;
if( Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) - timestamp >= 84600 ){
// some code if true
}else{
// other code if false
}
```

The timestamp is stored inside my indexedDB database, I'm facing the problem that after 24 hours it will not call the code that I have created if it's expired, when it's checked it will always result as if it's not older than 24 hours. I want that the timestamp expires after 24 hours. How I can fix?

Comment: Date.now() as of now is `1599633048756` ... divide that by 1000 you get  `1599633049` ... subtract `1599490350898` you get `-1597890717849` - so ... what does 24 hours have to do with anything ... that will ALWAYS be false .... just do `Date.now() - timestamp` ... since both Date.now() and timestamp are in milliseconds

Comment: ok thank you. I was using that solution because I've found a question here on SO where the timestamp difference was calclulated using this method.

Comment: @JaromandaX so the correct way is `if( Date.now() - timestamp >= 84600 )` right?

Comment: it's better than what you've got ... correct? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯